# React render external HTML DOM node into component when mounted

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have an external DOM node in which I display some dynamic content. That DOM node has to always be present on the page. I also have a component `MyComponent` that is mounted/unmounted at different times. When the component is mounted I want it's render method to render the existing `#data` div, and when it's unmounted it should put the div back.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        // Maybe somehow move the `#data` div inside this compoennt
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Maybe move the `#data` div back at the end of the </body> tag.
    }
    render() {
       // Here it should just return the existing `#data` div
    }
}
```

**MyComponent not mounted:**

```
<body>
<div id="app-root"></div>
<div id="data"></div> // has display: none while not used
</body>
```

**MyComponent mounted:**

```
<body>
<div id="app-root">
  // React stuff
  <my-component>
     <div id="data"></div>
   </my-component>
</div>
</body>
```

Is this possible (to render a plain HTML node inside a React component)?
Is there a better solution for my problem (have a div that's always on the page, `display: none;`, but when a component is mounted, render it inside that component)?

I use this for displaying Google Ads, so I have the adDisplayContainer that has to always be present (and re-used), but I only want to show it when a specific component is shown (and it has to be inside that component).

Comment: I think you need to create a HOC in which you are passing your component as a child component and it will give you your child component with adDisplayContainer.

Comment: So far I fixed my issue by having a component that's always visible on the page and which contains the ad container. The `MyComponent` is inside it and it can be mounted/unmounted at any point. The HTML structure is different than in my question, but I was not able to move the ad container without breaking the ad playing.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `createPortal` API from `ReactDOM`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#createportal

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But isn't this for the other way around, for when I have the content from my component and I want it rendered somewhere else? In my case I have the content somewhere else (outside React) and I want it render within my component.

Comment: i see, I'm trying to figuring out, and I'm found a hacky trick :rofl:

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-snyder-q8kgc